# hiding image in image using least significant bit

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, steganography

Following this walkthrough https://towardsdatascience.com/steganography-hiding-an-image-inside-another-77ca66b2acb1

Trying to implement lsb steganography similar to the walk through where an image is hidden within another image. However, the hidden image bits should be written into only the least significant bits of the cover image. The walk through in link merges MSB bits of the two images. So the 4 most significant bits of image to be hidden are written into 4 least significant bits of cover image, in that link.

What modifications need to be made to use only the least significant bits of cover image?

Have implemented hiding of a text message in image where last bit is used in every RGB pixel byte. Would like to do the same for hiding an image.

Comment: Please edit the code you have written to try solve this problem into your question.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from embedding the k MSBs of the secret image into the 8-k LSBs of the cover image, where k = 1 in your case. It's just that if you do this, the extracted image will have very low fidelity.